# How to start with Irrlich in android

Tags: android, irrlicht

I want to start with irrlich 3-d engine, i have downloaded the sdk, I want to run the sample project that come in sdk i want to know how to do that and port project to android. Also is there is any good tutorial and sample available for beginners.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333135/Wrapping-Irrlicht-For-Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this

- [Irrlicht Engine Tutorials](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/tutorials/)
- [Game development (Intro)](http://gamedevfan.blogspot.com/2009/10/irrlicht-engine-easy-tutorial-intro.html)
- [irrlicht tutorials online ebook](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/index.html)

---

For Android:

1.
[irrlicht port](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/MOF9GkqBOww)

2.[Project samples](https://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/)

3.[Programming 3D games on Android with Irrlicht](http://renzhi.ca/2011/05/19/programming-3d-games-on-android-with-irrlicht-and-bullet-part-1/)

4.[setup-the-irrlicht from game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17572/how-do-you-setup-the-irrlicht-and-bullet-engines-for-android-development)

P.s : I'm not familiar with irrlicht..but I interest this game engine..May be these links helpful

Comment: all the tutorials are meant for windows platform, i want to know how to port it to android or how to start using this engine in android.

Comment: edited with Android links..May be helpful to you